# Clicking two consecutive buttons while scraping a website with selenium in python

Tags: python, screen-scraping, clicking

I am trying to scrape the country information from the website below,
https://www.morningstar.com/etfs/xnas/vnqi/portfolio
which entails clicking the `'Country'` selection in the `Exposure` section, then moving through the 1, 2,3, etc. pages using the arrows at the bottom of the section. Nothing I have tried seems to work. Is there a way to do it using selenium in Python?

Many thanks!

Here is the code I used:

```
    urlpage   = 'https://www.morningstar.com/etfs/xnas/vnqi/portfolio'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='D:\Python\Python38\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get(urlpage)
    elements=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Country']")))
    for elem in elements:
        elem.click()
```

and this is the error message:

```
TimeoutException                          

Traceback (most recent call last)  
<ipython-input-3-bf16ea3f65c0> in <module>  
    23 driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='D:\Python\Python38\chromedriver.exe')  
     24 driver.get(urlpage)  
---> 25 elements=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Country']")))  
     26 for elem in elements:  
     27      elem.click()  
D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py in until(self, method, message)  
     78             if time.time() > end_time:  
     79                 break  
---> 80         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)  
     81   
     82     def until_not(self, method, message=''):  
TimeoutException: Message:
```

Sorry, not sure how to format the error message better. Thanks again.

Comment: Code:urlpage   = 'https://www.morningstar.com/etfs/xnas/vnqi/portfolio'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='D:\Python\Python38\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(urlpage)
elements=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Country']")))
for elem in elements:
    elem.click()

Comment: did you check HTML in web browser (using `Ctrl+U` or using `DevTool` in Chrome) ? I don't see `<a>` with text `Country` on this page. There is only `<input>` with `value="Country"` - and this is BIG difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you didn't check what you really have in `HTML`. So you didn't do the most important thing.

There is NO `<a>` with text `Country` on this page.

There is `<input>` with `value="Country"`

---

This code works for me

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.morningstar.com/etfs/xnas/vnqi/portfolio'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(2)

country = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="Country"]')
country.click()

time.sleep(1)
next_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@aria-label="Go to Next Page"]')
    
while True:
    
    # get data
    table_rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@class="sal-country-exposure__country-table"]//tr')
    for row in table_rows[1:]:  # skip header 
        elements = row.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span')  # relative xpath with `.//`
        print(elements[0].text, elements[1].text, elements[2].text)

    # check if there is next page
    disabled = next_page.get_attribute('aria-disabled')
    #print('disabled:', disabled)
    if disabled:
        break

    # go to next page        
    next_page.click()
    
    time.sleep(1)
```

Result

```
Japan 22.08 13.47
China 10.76 1.45
Australia 9.75 6.05
Hong Kong 9.52 6.04
Germany 8.84 5.77
Singapore 6.46 4.33
United Kingdom 6.22 5.77
Sweden 3.48 2.00
France 3.18 2.58
Canada 2.28 2.92
Switzerland 1.78 0.69
Belgium 1.63 1.31
Philippines 1.53 0.15
Israel 1.47 0.16
Thailand 0.98 0.09
India 0.87 0.11
South Africa 0.87 0.21
Taiwan 0.83 0.08
Mexico 0.80 0.33
Spain 0.62 0.84
Malaysia 0.54 0.08
Brazil 0.52 0.06
Austria 0.51 0.16
New Zealand 0.41 0.21
Indonesia 0.37 0.02
Norway 0.37 0.29
United States 0.29 44.09
Netherlands 0.24 0.19
Chile 0.21 0.01
Ireland 0.16 0.19
South Korea 0.15 0.00
Turkey 0.08 0.02
Russia 0.08 0.00
Finland 0.06 0.16
Poland 0.05 0.00
Greece 0.05 0.00
Italy 0.02 0.05
Argentina 0.00 0.00
Colombia 0.00 0.00
Czech Republic 0.00 0.00
Denmark 0.00 0.00
Estonia 0.00 0.00
Hungary 0.00 0.00
Latvia 0.00 0.00
Lithuania 0.00 0.00
Pakistan 0.00 0.00
Peru 0.00 0.00
Portugal 0.00 0.00
Slovakia 0.00 0.00
Venezuela 0.00 0.00
```

Comment: This worked really greater, thank you so much, I struggled with this for one day. What I did was I right-clicked the button that selects 'Country' and selected 'Inspect', and then on the right side I saw the <span class="mds-button__text">
            Country
          </span> section, but I didn't know exactly how to use it in my code (still very much a newbie at Python and html).  Thank you for the useful comments in the code as well, very helpful for understanding the more subtle parts.

Comment: Also, I clicked that this answer is useful, but because I don't have much history, it seems like it won't change the score assigned for your very useful answer.

Comment: sometimes it is good to check tag which keeps this `<span>`. Usually clickable are only `<a>`, `<input>` and `<button>` so I check if element is inside `<a>`, `<input>` or `<button>` . Sometimes there are other clickable elements but they have assigned some JavaScript code for this and you can see text `event` near its tag in `Inspect` in `DevTools`

Comment: you should have privilege to mark my answer as accepted and after few minutes you should have privilege to upvote it.

Comment: I put this answer to my examples on GitHub: [Python-Examples/__scraping__/morningstar.com](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/__scraping__/morningstar.com%20-%20selenium)

Comment: Thank you for the additional info above, I am still learning, so any and all such tidbits are useful. Also thanks for the github link, there's a wealth of examples there. I checked the answer as accepted, and will upvote as soon as I am able to.